# UWP accessing parameter from another class

Tags: c#, class, oop, parameters, uwp

Helloo all
I'm currently developing an UWP app that has TCP server in it and also some other functionality.
I developed a way to change background color by modifying 1 value from Mainpage.Caml.cs, code displayed in here:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public Windows.UI.Color backgroundColor;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
        MainConnection connector = new MainConnection();
        connector.StartConnection("0.0.0.0", "10500");
    }

    public Windows.UI.Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get => backgroundColor;
        set => backgroundColor = value;
    }
}
```

I also use getter and setter for backgroundColor.
As you can see I have another class, called ConnectionClass that handles connections and gets instructions what to do.
ConnectionClass is based on sample available public in MSDN:

```
    class MainConnection
{
    private bool connectionAllowed = true;

    public async void StartConnection(string net_aadress, string port_nr)
    {
        Windows.UI.Color backgroundColor;
        backgroundColor = ChangeBackground(255, 255, 255);
        try
        {
            var streamSocketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

            // The ConnectionReceived event is raised when connections are received.
            streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

            // Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
            await streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(port_nr);

            Debug.WriteLine("server is listening...");
            //Mainpage.viewModel.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 255);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus =
                Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
            Debug.WriteLine((webErrorStatus.ToString() != "Unknown" ? webErrorStatus.ToString() : ex.Message));
        }
    }

    private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender,
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

       do
        {
            RecievePacket();
            decodePacket(); //using switch case 
            switch(command)
            case endConnection:
                connectionAllowed = false;
                SendResponsePacket();
                break;
            case changeBackground:
                    //in here we find out that we have to set BackgroundColor to some other color. How can i pass R G and B values from here to main
                SendResponsePacket();
                break;

        }
        while(connectionAllowed == true)
    }



    Windows.UI.Color ChangeBackground(UInt16 r, UInt16 g, UInt16 b)
    {
        return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b);
    }

}
```

In ConnectionClass there is a Situation in there we suddenly find out from decoding packet that we have to change backgroundColor, but this porperty exists in MainPanel.xaml.cs
How can I access and change that parameter from scope I just pointed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is for your `Connection` class to expose an event for when an error occurs, and then `MainPage` can register a handler for the event and change its colour when the event is raised. This way, the low-level error in a network stack is not tightly-coupled with a high-level property of the UI (which would be a poor design).

If you need help creating an event, see [**Handling and Raising events** on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

Also it doesn't make sense that your field `backgroundColor` is `public` - it should be `private` since you have a `public` property getter/ setter. You could even omit the field altogether and just rely on auto-implemented property:

```
public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Followed documentation on MSDN and also this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0 and now it works like a charm.